# Asking for extension in submission of revision

Tags: peer-review

I submitted a paper to one of Elsevier journals. It got major revision and the submission time given to me was two months. Now the time is very near (10 days) and I think I cannot complete all changes to be incorporated. I asked for extension in due date of submission through editorial system using my login. Even after 4 days, there is no response. I am confused what should I do?
Is the deadline really hard and if I submit after a week or so, it will be rejected?

Comment: In general, these deadlines are to keep things in a timely and organised manner. It shouldn't be a problem getting an extension. I would send a polite reminder on the date of the deadline.

Answer (score 5):

Counting the days, you asked for an extension on 24.12. Not everyone has to be around during the holidays so next time ask maybe a little sooner.

It may depend on the field and journal, but this summer I asked for an extension and I got it. Also considering how certain deadlines are handled around the academia (like 3 months taking the referee to review a revision of the paper just to say its OK), you are probably going to be just fine.

Edit: I just remembered that some time before Christmas I was sent a proof to answer the questions from Journal of Mathematical Physics with a deadline of 48 hours. I guess it took maybe even more than 3 days to send it back and nobody did complain.

Comment: Do you think I should wait before again asking for extension?

Comment: If you are sure you sent the message correctly, then probably you do not need to do it again (it may even cause some confusion on the side of the journal). Maybe as pointed out in the comment bellow your question just let them know on the date of the deadline.
If you want to ask for extension for another paper then it is probably best to do it as soon as possible.